# Problem with CSS(floating) in ListView ItemTemplate!

Tags: asp.net, css, listview

i am new in CSS and have a problem with styling ListView Control in ItemTemplate tag.
my project language is rtl(persian) and i want to set the user image at the right and her/his infos to the left of the image.

 but this is the result:
[alt text http://sites.google.com/site/mahdiahmadirad/download-1/2009-12-08_134217.png?attredirects=0&d=1](http://sites.google.com/site/mahdiahmadirad/download-1/2009-12-08_134217.png?attredirects=0&d=1)

and here is the code for ListView:

```
<asp:ListView ID="NokListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <img alt="" src="./img/group.png"><br />
        <br />
        <fieldset>
            <legend>ليست کلي</legend>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </fieldset>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
        <hr />
    </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <img style="float: right;" alt="" src='<%# Eval("Gender","./img/{0}.png") %>' />
        <span>نام وارث:</span><%# Eval("FirstName") %>&nbsp;<%# Eval("LastName") %><span
            dir="ltr">(<%# Eval("Email") %>)</span><br />
        <span>نسبت او با شما:</span>
        <%# Eval("Relationship")%><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I set the style of  to float:right and it is working but as you see the template is like a Hierarchical list!
I want each Item place below the previous Item NOT in the front of.
please explain me what is exactly happening?! and how to fix it?

Comment: If you want to place the image at the left of the text you should use float:left.

Comment: excuse me. It was my mistake. I corrected it. I want to place the image at the right and texts at the left.

Comment: Either way, just place the two separate blocks of content in separate div tags with their own float settings. Make sure that you have enough total width set on the GridView to accomodate this. Also set widths on the two content divs. A screenshot would help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found My Answer here: [doctype.com](http://doctype.com/1TO)

and the complete fixed code is:

```
<ItemSeparatorTemplate>
<hr style="clear:right;" />
</ItemSeparatorTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <div style="clear: both;">
        <img style="float: right;" alt="" src='<%# Eval("Gender","./img/{0}.png") %>' />
        <span>نام وارث:</span><%# Eval("FirstName") %>&nbsp;<%# Eval("LastName") %>
        <span dir="ltr">(<%# Eval("Email") %>)</span><br />
        <span>نسبت او با شما:</span><%# Eval("Relationship")%><br />
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

So Look at the result:

[alt text http://sites.google.com/site/mahdiahmadirad/download-1/2009-12-09_103134.png?attredirects=0&d=1](http://sites.google.com/site/mahdiahmadirad/download-1/2009-12-09_103134.png?attredirects=0&d=1)

Answer (score 0):

Put the non-image data together in a div with float:left and see if that works?